# Do anonymous functions support optional parameters?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, optional-parameters

Is there a way to use optional parameters in anonymous functions implemented in MATLAB?

See the following example:

```
foo = @(x,y)(x+y+12)
```

Can `y` be an optional parameter in the above anonymous function, something like

```
foo = @(x,y?)(x+y+12)
```

and only use `y` when provided?

Comment: Why not use a vector of variable length if all the inputs are scalar already: `foo = @(x) (sum(x)+12)`? This would work with `foo(10)`, `foo([10 20])`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There's a concept in MATLAB called "variable-length input argument list", see [`varargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html). That can be used in anonymous functions in general, and specifically in your example:

```matlab
foo = @(varargin) sum(cell2mat(varargin)) + 12;

foo(10)           % 10 + 12
foo(10, 20)       % 10 + 20 + 12
foo(10, 20, 30)   % 10 + 20 + 30 + 12
```

```
ans =  22
ans =  42
ans =  72
```

`varargin` is a cell array, so that we need to convert it to a regular (numeric) array. Then we just need to sum these values and add 12.

Of course, that solution only works, if all passed arguments are of some numeric type.

Hope that helps!